# Simple encoding 'UTF-8' error

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, hebrew

The following string 'a' is in Hebrew:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = u'אבא'
print a
```

Produces the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database.py", line 13, in <module>
    print a
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: character maps to <undefined>
```

I went to see what is [Code Page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), and apparently it's for latin and greek (the string here is in hebrew).

So I tried:

```
a = 'אבא'
print a.decode('cp862').encode('cp862')
print a.decode('cp862').encode('utf-8')
print a.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
print a.decode('utf-8').encode('cp424')
print a.decode('utf-8').encode('cp856')
print a.decode('utf-8').encode('iso8859_8')
print a.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1255')
print a.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
```

and I get lots of outputs, but none of them is Hebrew.

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you doing anything else to the encoded string?

Comment: nope... What you see is what I do

Comment: What are you running Python from, the standard Windows `cmd` prompt?

Comment: yes, but I got my cmd box configured with hebrew fonts

Comment: See https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails ... this is a known problem with running Python from `cmd.exe`. There are workarounds, but using another terminal or python's IDLE may be the easier/better choice.

Comment: thanks. it doesn't work on IDLE on my Win7, but it does on my mac. weird stuff.

Comment: If you've configured Hebrew fonts for the console, change the code page to a Hebrew version, using `chcp 862` and try again.

Comment: @JohnFlatness, it's not cmd.exe. You'd have the same problem with the default OEM console codepage if you ran python.exe from Explorer. Just use ctypes to call  `SetConsoleOutputCP`, or use subprocess to run `chcp.com`.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said... Googled it and still, not sure it helps solving it.